# Identify a game: escape from a labyrinth of square cards on an alien spaceship

Tags: identify-this-game

Can anyone identify this game?

The players are contestants trapped in a labyrinth on an alien spaceship, racing to find the exit.

Locations are square cards that can be rotated during the game.  At the beginning of the game all locations are upside-down, getting revealed as the players explore.

In some locations players can find items that they can use to help themselves or hinder the other contestants.

It is a rather new game, created some time in the last five years, I think.  The designer lives in California.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds even more like [Alien Labyrinth](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/137478/alien-labyrinth).
[image]

Comment: Fun fact: the name was basically given by the question's title :D

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you're thinking of [Space Maze](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/97655/space-maze)?
[image]

Comment: This isn't it, but I can certainly see the similarities!